# Create a new list from another list based on condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, filter, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a new list from another list based on condition:

```
lst = [("Id01","Code1",1),("Id01","#instr1",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id01","#instr4",1),
       ("Id01","Code2",1),("Id01","#instr3",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id02","Code2",1),
       ("Id02","#instr2",1),("Id02","#instr5",1)]

table, instrlist = '', ''; code, instructions = [], []; qty = 0

for idx, l in enumerate(lst):
    table = l[0]
    if not l[1].startswith('#'):
        code = l[1]; qty = l[2]; instructions = []
    else:
        instructions.append(l[1])
    print idx, table, code, instructions, qty
```

Every time the code is present on the tuples after a tuple containing '#', I need to transmit the correct line in to another part of the program and reset to start processing another one. I've put a series of conditions and I got this result:

```
0 Id01 Code1 [] 1
1 Id01 Code1 ['#instr1'] 1
2 Id01 Code1 ['#instr1', '#instr2'] 1
3 Id01 Code1 ['#instr1', '#instr2', '#instr4'] 1
4 Id01 Code2 [] 1
5 Id01 Code2 ['#instr3'] 1
6 Id01 Code2 ['#instr3', '#instr2'] 1
7 Id02 Code2 [] 1
8 Id02 Code2 ['#instr2'] 1
9 Id02 Code2 ['#instr2', '#instr5'] 1
```

However the result I really need is

```
3 Id01 Code1 ['#instr1', '#instr2', '#instr4'] 1
6 Id01 Code2 ['#instr3', '#instr2'] 1
9 Id02 Code2 ['#instr2', '#instr5'] 1
```

Of what condition I need to filter again?

I'm not skilled enough to use list comprehension or a built-in filter, and I would like to leave the code as much readable as possible (for a newbie), at least until I will learn more.

**UPDATE:**

The solution offered by **jpp** seems to be the most efficient and readable:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count, chain

lst = [("Id01","Code1",1),("Id01","#instr1",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id01","#instr4",1),
       ("Id01","Code2",1),("Id01","#instr3",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id02","Code2",1),
       ("Id02","#instr2",1),("Id02","#instr5",1)]

d = defaultdict(list)
enums = []
c = count()

for ids, action, num in lst:
    if not action.startswith('#'):
        my_ids, my_action = ids, action
        enums.append(next(c))
    else:
        d[(my_ids, my_action)].append([action, num])
        next(c)
enums = enums[1:] + [len(lst)]

for idx, ((key1, key2), val) in enumerate(d.items()):
    print (enums[idx]-1, key1, key2, list(chain.from_iterable(val)), val[0][-1])
```

However I'm facing some issues.

1. For some reasons the order is wrong (the last line became the first one):
   Results in:

   (3, 'Id02', 'Code2', ['#instr2', 1, '#instr5', 1], 1) <--- should be the last one

   (6, 'Id01', 'Code1', ['#instr1', 1, '#instr2', 1, '#instr4', 1], 1)

   (9, 'Id01', 'Code2', ['#instr3', 1, '#instr2', 1], 1)
2. The numeric field on a tuple is not always '1' and sometimes the script will not respect it (missing information by my side) because it take always the number found in the tuple. Needs to be paired with the 'Code' tuple and can be omitted.

I'm working on it and I will update my post as soon as I will resolve the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to correct the issues I found on the solution offered by jpp (my bad, I need to take some spare time to study more), I've elaborated my own code. Clearly is not "the python way", but works fine:

```
lst = [("Id01","Code1",1),("Id01","#instr1",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id01","#instr4",1),
       ("Id01","Code2",1),("Id01","#instr3",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id02","Code2",1),
       ("Id02","#instr2",1),("Id02","#instr5",1)]

instr, newline = [], []
for idx, codex, qtx in reversed(lst): #reversed list is more simple to read

    if codex.startswith('#'):
        instr.insert(0, codex) #here I'm creating the tuple in the right order
    else:
        newline += tuple([(idx, codex, qtx) + tuple(instr)])
        instr = []

newline = newline[::-1] #reversed the list to respect the order of the original list (lst) 

for n in newline:
    print n
```

Results in:

```
('Id01', 'Code1', 1, '#instr1', '#instr2', '#instr4')
('Id01', 'Code2', 1, '#instr3', '#instr2')
('Id02', 'Code2', 1, '#instr2', '#instr5')
```

The basic idea is to revert the input list (lst), since is more simple to elaborate condition on a for loop. After formatting the tuples I needed to reverse the output list (newline) to have the correct order.
I took the liberty to add some comments to better reading for newbies like me.

I know is a dirty coding and I'm quite sure I can do better, but for now I have serious issues combining various list comprehension routines. 
In time I will improve my coding skill.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.defaultdict` offers an intuitive solution. The idea is to create a dictionary with keys set as the first two components of a tuple if the second does not begin with `'#'`. Then iterate the dictionary to `print` in your desired format.

There is some messy work with `itertools.count` to get your desired indices. I'm sure you can improve on this effort.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count, chain

lst = [("Id01","Code1",1),("Id01","#instr1",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id01","#instr4",1),
       ("Id01","Code2",1),("Id01","#instr3",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id02","Code2",1),
       ("Id02","#instr2",1),("Id02","#instr5",1)]

d = defaultdict(list)
enums = []
c = count()

for ids, action, num in lst:
    if not action.startswith('#'):
        my_ids, my_action = ids, action
        enums.append(next(c))
    else:
        d[(my_ids, my_action)].append([action, num])
        next(c)

enums = enums[1:] + [len(lst)]
```

Result:

```
for idx, ((key1, key2), val) in enumerate(d.items()):
    print(enums[idx]-1, key1, key2, list(chain.from_iterable(val)), val[0][-1])

3 Id01 Code1 ['#instr1', 1, '#instr2', 1, '#instr4', 1] 1
6 Id01 Code2 ['#instr3', 1, '#instr2', 1] 1
9 Id02 Code2 ['#instr2', 1, '#instr5', 1] 1
```

Comment: This kind of coding remind me how small is my knowledge of python. Thanks, is not much readable for me (but I will analyze the script with care) but simply... Works! 
As far I can see there is just a small issue: the items starting with '#' are lists in a list. Will be possible have it already as a single list (not nested)?
Please note the idx of the list I have put was just needed to identify the position on debug. It' s not needed or at least will be ignored. 
I do apologize, was a missing information.

Comment: Great! I' m reading right now about collections and intertools modules. Thanks man, I've completely missed those modules in the past.

Comment: A little help, if you run again your script you will notice the idx 9 is the first showing where you state print(enums[idx]-1, key1, key2, list(chain.from_iterable(val)), val[0][-1])... 
Should be index 9 but is index 3.

Comment: @FedericoLeoni, Sorry, comments are *really* bad for code. I can't read it at all. If there's a specific bit that you need explaining, let me know. As I said, there are bits you should be able to improve *if you understand the code*. If you don't understand one particular bit, let me know & I'm more than happy to explain :).

Comment: Yes, add code in comment is virtually impossible. I' m starting to understand the logic, is much simple of what I thought. But could you gently have a look on the result of your script? The print statement at the end of the for loop doesn't respect the order of the list as the one you shown in your post: the last tuple is on the first line when I run the script on pycharm.

Comment: @FedericoLeoni, Sure, so I'm a bit confused. The output that's printed is precisely what I see in my answer. And also it's precisely the same as in your question. What do you expect instead? If you need another output, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50337070/edit) your question so we don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools 
import re
lst = [("Id01","Code1",1),("Id01","#instr1",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id01","#instr4",1),
   ("Id01","Code2",1),("Id01","#instr3",1),("Id01","#instr2",1),("Id02","Code2",1),
   ("Id02","#instr2",1),("Id02","#instr5",1)]
results = {a:list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
code_groupings = {a:[[c, list(d)] for c, d in itertools.groupby(b, key=lambda x:'Code' in x[1])] for a, b in results.items()}
count = 0
last_code = None
for a, b in sorted(code_groupings.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]):
  for c, results in b:
    if c:
      count += 3
      last_code = results[0][1]
    else:
      print('{} {} {} {} 1'.format(count, a, last_code, str([i[1] for i in results])))
```

Output:

```
3 Id01 Code1 ['#instr1', '#instr2', '#instr4'] 1
6 Id01 Code2 ['#instr3', '#instr2'] 1
9 Id02 Code2 ['#instr2', '#instr5'] 1
```

Comment: The solution offered by @jpp seems more clean  (for my eyes) but thanks man! I will study both and see which one fit better.

Comment: I see you use a  fixed ' 1 ' on your print statement, but in true this is a value that could change, as is a quantity...

Comment: @FedericoLeoni What is the rule regarding its value?

Comment: The last number in a tuple is the quantity of the code needed pulled out from the DB. The quantity of an #instr code respect the quantity of the code and can be omitted.